# ¿Como puedo insertar campos de una tabla con campos de esa misma tabla?

Tags: mysql

le escribo el ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer.Tengo una tabla en mysql de la siguiente manera

```
create table usuarios(
  id varchar(10) primary key not null,
  apellido1 varchar(20),
  apellido2 varchar(20),
  nombre1 varchar(20),
  nombre2 varchar(20),
  nombreusu CONCAT' (apellido1||' '||apellido2||' '||nombre1||'  '||nombre2)'
)
```

lo que quiero es que al momento de insertar datos automaticamente queden los datos cocatenados en el campo nombreusu

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MySQL usas?

Answer (score 1):

PARA HACER ESO EXISTEN LOS TRIGGER, LO QUE DEBES HACER ES HACER UN TRIGGER ***BEFORE INSERT*** (ANTES DE INSERTAR) LO QUE HAREMOS ES ASIGNARLE EL VALOR AL CAMPO ***nombreusu*** EL RESULTADO DE CANCATENAR LOS PARAMETROS  USANDO ***NEW*** QUE ES EL ***PSEUDO-REGISTRO*** QUE NOS PERMITER OBTENER LOS VALORES NUEVOS QUE SE VAN INSERTAR.

EL TRIGGER QUEDARÍA DE LA SIGUIENTE MANERA:

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_before_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON usuarios
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.nombreusu = CONCAT(NEW.apellido1, NEW.apellido2, NEW.nombre1, NEW.nombre2, NEW.nombreusu);
END;
```

AHORA HACEMOS UN INSERT A LA TABLA:

```
INSERT INTO usuarios(id,apellido1,apellido2,nombre1,nombre2,nombreusu)VALUES (7,'AAA','BBB','CCC','DDD','')
```

AHORA HACEMOS UN SELECT A LA TABLA:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios;
```

EL RESULTADO ES EL SIGUIENTE:

> 1 |   AAA | BBB | CCC | DDD | AAABBBCCCDDD

**NOTA:** PARA QUE FUNCIONE CORRECTAMENTE DEBES DE ASIGNARLE UN VALOR PARA EL CAMPO **nombreusu** A LA HORA DE HACER EL **INSERT INTO** COMO EL EJEMPLO DE ARRIBA QUE SE LE ASIGNO '', SI NO LE PASAS NINGÚN VALOR SE GUARDARÁ COMO (Null).

SALUDOS!